# How do I add an middleware to my profile route in NextJS-13. I do not want anyone else other than the authenticated user to access the route

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to make a getProfile page for my nextjs app. However I want to protect the API route. The api route is as follows http://localhost:3000/api/user/123456 . I do not want any other user other than the current employee logged in with employeeid 123456 to access the route. I am handling sesssions by NextAuth.

I tried making a middleware file and passing hte handler through it. But I am unable to handle the routing now. help me with this.
This is the middleware file

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const requireAuth = (handler) => async (req, res) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
  
    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.redirect('/login');
    } 
    if (session.user.EmployeeID !== req.params.id) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 });
    }
  
    return handler(req, res);
  };
  
  export default requireAuth;
```

This below is the route/employeeId/route.js

```
import User from "@models/user";
import { ConnectToDb } from "@utils/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import requireAuth from "@utils/middleware";
export default requireAuth(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      return handleGet(req, res);
    }
  
    // Handle other HTTP methods if needed
  
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Method not allowed' }, { status: 405 });
  });
  
  async function handleGet(req, res) {
    const { params } = req;
    const { EmployeeID } = params;
  
    try {
      await ConnectToDb();
      const user = await User.findOne({ EmployeeID });
  
      if (!user) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'User not found' }, { status: 401 });
      }
  
      return NextResponse.json({ user }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this its work for me

in your middleware.js

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(request) {

  const session = await getSession({ request });

  if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('/login');
  }

  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  // Get employee ID from path 
  const pathParts = pathname.split('/');
  const employeeId = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];

  // Validate employee ID 
  if (!employeeId.match(/^\d+$/)) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('/invalid-employee');
  }

  return NextResponse.next();

}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/employee/:employeeId'], // Provide your client side page folder name 
};
```

> In the matcher please provide the route of your clientside id page like this